# The CSS does not work properly with UL and LI tags with graphics in before

Tags: css

I have a very basic knowledge of CSS and I need to make some adjustments to an existing document. Below is a snippet of my HTML+CSS code and an image with the browser output. Could someone please help me fix it so that 'Some longer text' does not overlap the element below, and so that text wrapping starts below the V icon?

I will be very grateful for any help.

```css
:root {
    --background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    --page-bg-color: white;
    --page-width: 21cm;
    --page-height: 29.7cm;
    --font-family: "Poppins";
    --font-p-size: 9pt;
    --font-h1-size: 18pt;
    --font-secondary-size: 11pt;
    --border-radius: 9pt;
    --color-primary: {{primary-color}};
}

body {
    background: var(--background);
    font-family: var(--font-family), sans-serif;
    font-size: var(--font-p-size);
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page {
    background: var(--page-bg-color);
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
    width: var(--page-width);
    height: var(--page-height);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 24pt 40pt 46pt 40pt;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .page:last-of-type {
        margin-bottom: -1px;
    }

@media print {
    @page {
        size: A4 portrait;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 99%;
    }

    * {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }

    .page {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 var(--font-p-size);
    list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}

    ul .check::before {
        content: "\2713";
        color: var(--color-primary);
        padding-left: 40pt;
    }

    ul li::before {
        content: "\25AA";
        color: var(--color-primary);
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1em;
        margin-left: -1em;
        padding-left: 20pt;
        padding-bottom: 10pt;
    }

ul li .check {
font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1em;
        margin-left: -1em;
        padding-left: 20pt;
        padding-bottom: 10pt;
}

/* Proposal section */

section.proposal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-top: 13pt;
}

    section.proposal .options {
        line-height: 0.4;
        margin-top: 12pt;
    }

    .small-margin-bottom {
        margin-bottom: 11pt;
    }


/* bordered-card */

.bordered-card {
    border: 1pt solid black;
    padding: 7pt 15pt;
    margin-right: 20pt;
    position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, lightgray);
}

.bordered-card img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    right: -50px;
}

.bordered-card p {
    padding-bottom: 5pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <section class="proposal">
        <div class="options">
            <p>Some Text</p>
            <ul class="insurance-coverage-table">
      <li>TEXT 1</li>
      <li>TEXT 2</li>

      <ul class="small">
        <li class="check">Some short text</li>
        <li class="check">Some short text</li>
        <li class="check">Some longer text aaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa</li>
        <li class="check">Some short text</li>
      </ul>

    </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bordered-card">
            <p><b>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</b> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            <p><b>Text1a</b><br />text1b</p>
            <p><b>Text1a</b><br />text1b</p>
            <p><b>Text1a</b><br />text1b</p>
            <p><b>Text1a</b><br />text1b</p>
            <p><b>Text1a</b><br />text1b</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The overlap issue appears to stem mostly from the fact, that you are setting such a low `line-height: 0.4` for `section.proposal .options` ...

Comment: increase your line-height and you won't have the overlapping text

Comment: Ok, thnx. But What about  move aaaaaaa aaaa text to right and start from V position

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You can’t have a ul as a direct child of a ul.